# Is there any way to filter all previous elements, by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I have a masonry gallery with *ul / li* elements. To make them responsive I am adding to each '**li**' element it's column number as a class, so I can sort them later.

I am trying to get previous elements height in column before adding new one. So basically the column height before new '**li**' element.

I am using **prevAll()**, to get all previous elements, but I can't combine height calculation and filtering columns. So tried to achieve it with **each()**, with filter, and with changing selector, I added that part of the code.

```
var that= this;
that.prevAll = $(this).prevAll();


that.top += $(this).prevAll('.column' + that.current_column).height(); 
// selector

that.top += that.prevAll.filter('.column' + that.current_column).height(); 
// filter

that.prevAll.each(function(){
  if(that.prevAll.hasClass('.column' + that.current_column)) {
  that.top += that.prevAll.height() + that.settings.imegesGap;
 };            
});
// .each
```

DOM

jQuery

```
 $this.addClass('column' + that.current_column);
 $this.addClass('row' + that.row);
```

HTML

```
<ul class="mosaic1">
    <li ><img src="img/test.png"></li>
    <li ><img src="img/test6.jpg"></li>
    <li ><img src="img/test4.jpg"></li>
    <li ><img src="img/test.3.jpg"></li>
    <li ><img src="img/test7.jpg"></li>
    <li ><img src="img/test5.png"></li>
</ul>
```

The main problem with  'each' function.It keeps summing up.

P.S. This is my first question here, so sorry if description not good enough.

Comment: Looks like you're giving an invalid selector to both the `prevAll()` and `filter()` calls.

Comment: Please provide your DOM structure as well. `column` selector is not a valid selector. It should either be `#myId` or `.myClassName` or `button` (last one could be any element name). If *column* would be a class, it would look like: `.prevAll(".column")` or `.prevAll(".column " + that.current_column)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a mistake in here, but the code was fine, I updated my question.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML structure for your question? Also please format the question so as to include all code inside code blocks. It will help everyone to answer you quickly and better.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I missed space, the HTML is full, everything else is done in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem was  each function, it worked wrong because I did not reset that.top  at the begging. So the  correct way is this

```
var that= this;
that.prevAll = $(this).prevAll();
that.top = 0;

that.prevAll.each(function(){
  if(that.prevAll.hasClass('.column' + that.current_column)) {
   that.top += that.prevAll.height() + that.settings.imegesGap;
  }; 
enter code here
```